# Use NodeJS's process in Vue CLI project

Tags: node.js, vue.js, es6-promise

I have a challenge using the Node's `process.on` function in the Vue CLI project's `main.js` file.
I have the following code in the file.

```
process.on("unhandledRejection", function(reason, promise){
  console.log("Unhandled", reason, promise); // log all your errors, "unsuppressing" them.
  throw reason; // optional, in case you want to treat these as errors
});
```

The project builds but when the app is opened on the browser, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: process.on is not a function
```

How do I configure the project so that I can use the Node's process?
Am I not understanding NodeJS in this context?
Is there something I am missing?
Any assistance is appreciated thanks.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Are you sure you are running in a NodeJS context ? How do you run the main.js file ?

Comment: @Seblor I run the project using the 'vue-cli-service serve' script

Comment: The command `vue-cli-service serve` runs a dev server, so your main.js file runs in the browser, not in the NodeJS context.

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it now, but is there a way to catch the promises unhandledRejections in the browser?